# Rectangular box without a top has a volume of 216 in$^3$. Find dimensions of the box with the smallest surface area.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, volume

> Rectangular box without a top has a volume of 216 in$^3$. Find dimensions of the box with the smallest surface area. Use second derivative test.

So this is what I came up with not sure where it will lead me. 
$$
216=xyz\\
z=216/xy\\
$$
So
$$
\text{Surface Area}= 2xy+2xz+yz = 2xy+2x(216/xy)+y(216/xy).
$$
That's all I got, don't know where to got from there.

Comment: After replacing the z's in the surface area formula this was the result: 2xy+432/y+432/x. Then differentiate both relative to y and to x and got the same result: 2x^2 y^2 +432x+432y

Comment: There is information missing from your question. There are many boxes of different dimensions all having volume 216 cubic inches. Are you looking for one with the smallest surface area? Also note that your surface area formula is incorrect - you did not take into account that the box has no top.

Comment: Yes the box with the smallest surface area, and thanks for correcting the surface area formula totally forgot about that.

Comment: This is now a constrained optimization problem. You want to minimize the surface area subject to the volume constraint $216=xyz$. Try the Lagrange multiplier method. (Also, you should note which of the variables $x,y,z$ is the height of the box, as this matters when you give your answer. The length and width can be interchanged without changing the surface area, but the height cannot be interchanged with the length or width without changing the surface area.)

Answer (score 3):

We don't need any calculus to find the minimum surface area - AM-GM works fine.

Solution 1. AM-GM

We have the surface area as $xy+2yz+2zx$ with the constraint of $xyz=216$.$$xy+2yz+2zx = xy+\frac{432}{x}+\frac{432}{y} \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{xy \cdot \frac{432}{x} \cdot \frac{432}{y}} = 3\sqrt[3]{432^2} = 108 \sqrt[3]{4}$$
The equality holds at $x=y=6\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $z=3\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Solution 2. Second Derivative Test

Again, the surface area is $f(x,y)=xy+\frac{432}{x}+\frac{432}{y}$.

Now $f_x(x,y)=y-\frac{432}{x^2}=0$ and $f_y(x,y)=x-\frac{432}{y^2}=0$.

This gives $x^2y=xy^2=432$, so $x=y=6\sqrt[3]{2}$, and $z=3\sqrt[3]{2}$ follows.

Now $f_{xx}(x,y)=\frac{864}{x^3}$, $f_{yy}(x,y)=\frac{864}{y^3}$, and $f_{xy}(x,y)=f_{yx}(x,y)=1$.

We have $$D = f_{xx}(x,y) \cdot f_{yy}(x,y) - f_{xy}^2(x,y) = \frac{864^2}{x^3y^3}-1 = \frac{864^2}{432^2}-1=3 > 0$$

So we have a local minimum. We are done.

Comment: Thanks it helped me.